# Is there a hotkey to change the browser context between the devtools and current page?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

If I have a webpage open and the devtools open at the same time, is there a hotkey that switches the browser context between the two?

For example, by default `Control + l` selects the address bar if I've last clicked on the webpage but `Control + l` also clears the devtools console if I've last clicked the devtools. Is there a way to switch my browser context between the two without having to first click?

Comment: AFAIK no. I simply undock devtools to a separate floating window to switch between page/devtools.

Comment: Never considered that, that works as solution for my workflow. Thanks.